# Get a drop-down list from another sheet based on lookup

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, data-validation, list, dropdownlist

I have a list of CA in my Source sheet that looks like this:

[image: source sheet]

And in my main sheet I need to get a dropdown list of "little a" for each CA, like this:
[image: dropdown list]

Main sheet:
[image: main sheet]

Sheets:
[image: two files]

For example: Handerson has CA_1, so I need to have a dropdown list with a11, a12, a13 and a14. Dude also has CA_1, so it needs a dropdown list with a11..a14, Ma ma has CA_2, so I need a dropdown list with a21, a22. etc. So each time I add a new people with a specific CA, I need to have the correct associate dropdown list, so if I add "Dogg" with "CA_4" I need to have a41, a42 and a43.

Comment: How do you differenciate between Henderson and Dude as they are both CA_1? Should little a related to CA_1 be listed for them?

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1641232/edit) your question to reflect what you mean by list as it renders my answer null and void. And it will help others to give better answer.

Comment: It's my first time using superuser and stackoverflow. So sorry for wasting your time.
But thanks for helping me :)

Comment: No worries. The better explanation you give, the easier it will be for others to understand your question and answer more appropriately.

Comment: Yes it seems logic, I hope my new explanations are better and clearer

Comment: From the provided data, it is not clear which "little a" corresponds to Henderson. So we cannot help until you explain.

Comment: For exemple : Handerson has CA_1, so I need to have a dropdown list with a11, a12, a13 and a14.
Dude also has CA_1, so it needs a dropdown list with a11..a14, Ma ma has CA_2, so I need a dropdown list with a21, a22. etc.

So each time I add a new people with a specific CA, I need to have the correct associate dropdown list, so if I add "Dogg" with "CA_4" I need to have a41, a42 and a43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new sheet `Sources2` and in cell `A3` put this formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(Sources!$2:$1000,,MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(Param!B3,"CA","CA_"),Sources!$1:$1,0)))
```

[image]

Copy the formula down.

In sheet `Param` select cell `C3`

*Data* -> *Data validation* -> `=Sources2!3:3`

[image]

SAVE

Copy down

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude, all I need ;)